# Uploading Image with PIL+twython on twitter without saving it

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

After much searching I finally found it. Here's the response.

**Step 1**

code for the user to provide the link and for PIL to resize it according to some conditions (not relevant to the question). 
PIL opens the image file link like this:

```
img=Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))
```

where `url` is the link.

**Step2**

then PIL must save it AND seek(0) on the io.BytesIO class:

```
blob = io.BytesIO()
img.save(blob, 'JPEG')
blob.seek(0)
response = twitter.upload_media(media=blob);
```

**Step 3**
Proceed according to the documendation:

```
twitter.update_status(status='Checkout this cool image!', media_ids=[response['media_id']])
```

Twython's documendation is outdated and `StringIO()` has changed package and also doesn't take bytes objects. I also can't get the logic behind making a bytes object to a string and then send it as a bytes object.

https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/advanced_usage.html

The `media` parameter also takes `io.BytesIO` class objects as shown above and in this simpler example below:

```
response = twitter.upload_media(media=io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content));
```